# drupal user_save() function does not update existing user but create a new one

Tags: php, drupal-7, save, updates

user_save function does not update my user but throw exception :
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'name'
because it suppose I need to make a new user object and it has the same name of the other.
my code is in follow:

```
// load user object
$account = user_load($user->uid);

// update some user property
$saved = $account->selected_keyword;
if(isset($saved))
    array_push($termIds,$saved);
$account->selected_keyword = $termIds;

// save existing user
try {
    user_save((object) array('uid' => $account->uid), (array) $account);
}catch(Exception $e){
    print_r($e);exit;
}
```

so how can I fix it?

Comment: I've read https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2013-04-12/solved-programmatically-addupdate too but it doesn't help me

Comment: I've tryed https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_update/7.x too but it's not possible to insert an undefined column value.

Comment: Are you sure that `selected_keyword` could be a value of `$user` property?

Comment: Shouldn't be `field_selected_keyword['und']...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood my problem was with `userId`, I was getting the user Id by `drupal_anonymous_user()` function so the `user_save` was creating a new user and it was wrong I needed to use global `$user;`

Also I needed to create new field by `field_create_field()` function of field module.

Answer (score 0):

[`user_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/7.x) needs to have `$account` as first argument, not as second. You should create an array for the edits:

```
$account = user_load($user->uid);

$edit = array(
  'field_some_custom_field' => array(
    'und' => array(
      0 => array(
        'value' => $new_value,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

user_save($account, $edit);
```

You should adapt to your case for the `selected_keyword` property.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. but it's not working any more and creating a new object too.